# Truth Tables for Digital Circuits

Tags: logic

I'm currently learning Truth Tables for Digital Circuits as shown below, but it gets a bit confusing for me to create the truth tables. Could someone explain or guide me along?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z38Wk.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnrDz.png

Comment: Each input can be a $1$ or a $0$. For each combination trace the signals through the circuit to determine its output. You have $3$ inputs so your truth table should have $2^3$ rows.

Comment: Do one thing at a time. Start by assigning variables for each output then you start from left to right. Which is the leftmost variable which has not yet been determined? Determine it. Which is the next leftmost variable... and so on.

Comment: John's hint is the more quick way, for a few inputs. $2^3$ rows, one final column (if one output), but in between you can put some auxiliary columns to help track the ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the diagram into a formula.

Let's consider the most difficult of the two circuits, that is that referenced at https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnrDz.png

Put on your schema three lanes vertically: the first containing the two logic gates NOT and NAND in the leftmost part of the diagram, the second containing the gates in the middle part of the diagram (two ANDs and a NOT), and the third containing the next two gates (a NOT and a NOR).

Now start from the Y output. It is given by the and of its inputs that you can call $X_{3,1}$ and $X_{3,2}$ where the first subscript represents the lane containing the gates of which the signal $X$ is output and the second just indicates the order in which the "wire" on which the signal travels appears in the lane from top to bottom. So you can write:

$$Y = X_{3,1} X_{3,2}\tag{1}$$

Now write the expression of $X_{3,1}$ and $X_{3,2}$ considered as outputs of the gate in the third lane: these espressions involves the outputs of the gates in the preceding lane 2, and so they are:

$$X_{3,1} = \overline{X_{2,1}}\tag{2}$$
$$X_{3,2} = \overline{X_{2,2} + X_{2,3}}\tag{3}$$

Now you can put together $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$.

$$Y=\overline{X_{2,1}} ~\overline{X_{2,2} + X_{2,3}}\tag{4}$$

Working on the second lane to determine the expression of the input of the gate in the third lane as output of the gates in the second lane, you have

$$X_{2,1}=X_{1,1} X_{2,2}\tag{5}$$
$$X_{2,2}=X_{1,2} X_{1,3}\tag{6}$$
$$X_{2,3}=\overline{X_{1,3}}\tag{7}$$

Putting these latest espressions into $(4)$

$$Y=\overline{X_{1,1} X_{1,2} X_{1,3}} \overline{X_{1,2} X_{1,3} + \overline{X_{1,3}}}\tag{8}$$

In the end, proceeding still backward, yor reach the inputs:
$$X_{1,1} = \overline{A}\tag{9}$$
$$X_{1,2} = B\tag{10}$$
$$X_{1,3} = \overline{BC}\tag{11}$$

So using $(8)$ it is:
$$Y=\overline{\overline{A} B \overline{B C}} ~\overline{B \overline{B C} +B C}\tag{12}$$
Now you can compute: when $A=0$, $B=0$, $C=0$ then $Y=1$, when $A=0$, $B=0$, $C=1$ then $Y=1$, ... You need to proceed on with all the 8 input configurations possible.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} & \text{Y} \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}

Note that if you know a little of propositional calculus you can get a simplified formula for $Y$ from $(12)$, where the left operand of the outer AND is equal to $\overline{\overline{A} B \overline{B C}} = A+B\rightarrow C$ and the right operand to $\overline{B \overline{B C} +B C} = \overline{B}$, so 
$$Y=(A+B\rightarrow C)\overline{B}\tag{13}$$
that is,
$$Y=\overline{B}\tag{14}$$

Comment: It looks to me like: if $A$, $B$, $C$ all have a truth value of True (1), then the output ($Y$) has a truth value of True (1).  So $Y \ne \overline{B}$

Comment: @paw88789 $Y$ is False when $A$, $B$, $C$ all have value True. Try again and tell me. Thanks anyway for your comment. My answer is for the "circuit" referenced as https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnrDz.png I did not see that the OP put 2 references. They are next to each other that I can tell that they are two. So probably you are talking about the other circuit that i have not even analyzed.

Comment: @paw88789 I'm going to edit my answer saying what circuit I'm taking into consideration. Thanks. +1