# Truth Tables for Logic Digital Circuits

Tags: logic

I'm trying to draw a truth table from the digital logic circuits, I suppose the one on the left is right, but the one on the right is confusing and I'm lost on how to start. I did some labeling and I'm unsure on this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this would be more on topic on the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Please note the difference between AND gates and NAND gates (and also OR vs NOR). E.g I is B NAND C rather than B AND C. ALso,  D should be NOT A AND E rather than A AND E.

Comment: You're making it harder for yourself by labeling the intermediate results in a sequence that doesn't respect how they depend on each other. With these labels you have to compute the I column before the E column, and the E column before the D column ...

Comment: Just a quick observation:  You need to ensure you are accounting for the NOT gates.  E.g.  A is input to the not gate, it is negated upon leaving the not gate.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, @Henning.

Comment: A few good suggestions have already been offered.  If, moreover, you know the basic laws of Boolean algebra (in particular, De Morgan's laws) an effective way to check your truth table is to compute, for each gate, the function of the primary inputs it implements symbolically.  For instance, in the first circuit, $X := \neg\neg(A \wedge B) \wedge \neg B = A \wedge B \wedge \neg B = 0$.  The expressions in the circuit on the right remain simple throughout.  For example, the node you labeled $H$ implements $\neg B$.

Comment: you have already asked this question here  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2370850 and I gave an answer there!

Answer (score 0):

Start with $A=B=C=0$. Write the truth values on the line after they pass through each gate as $0$ or $1$. Solve each column of gates from left to right to ensure that you have the inputs for the next column of gates. Repeat with the seven other possible starting truth values for for $A,B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 0):

The first one seems correct. You can easily check your results by creating the circuit in this site [1](https://academo.org/demos/logic-gate-simulator/).

A good methodology is to write down the values of 0 or 1 before and after each gate as CyclotomicField said and repeat for every combination of A,B and C, using a pencil so as to erase the previous values before writing down the next combination.